# How to display related data with Laravel JSON API

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

---

I've created an API in Laravel. I have some tables with relationships and I'm receiving JSON like this:

```js
{
  content: "Lorem ipsum",
  created_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
  deleted_at: null,
  group_id: 1,
  rating: 6,
  updated_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
  user_id: 1
}
```

But I'd like to receive something like this:

```js
 {
      content: "Lorem ipsum",
      created_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
      deleted_at: null,
      group_id: 1,
      rating: 6,
      updated_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
      user: {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Doe",
        avatar: "file.jpg"
      }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I see the `php` tag but no `php` code

Comment: Add `->with('user')`

Comment: kerbholz thanks it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `user` data by using relationships.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

For this you will first need to setup the relationship. For example in the Model you add something like:

```
public function user() {
    $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now you can use this relationship to get the user as part of your query by doing something like this

```
Model::with('user')->where('this', 'that')->first();
```

When you return this as a JSON response, the `user` will be available as you need.

You may need to hide some fields from the `User` that gets sent as part of the response. You can do this by changing the `$visible` in the Model

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your model it will return users data but column name should be `user_id`. I hope your problem will resolve this.

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = {
  content: "Lorem ipsum",
  created_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
  deleted_at: null,
  group_id: 1,
  rating: 6,
  updated_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
  user_id: 1
}

$a['user'] = User::find($a['user_id']);


you will get

{
      content: "Lorem ipsum",
      created_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
      deleted_at: null,
      group_id: 1,
      rating: 6,
      updated_at: "2018-03-13 16:51:21",
      user: {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Doe",
        avatar: "file.jpg"
      }
}
```